# Compare two string values and return its index in java

Tags: java, string, compare, substring

I have two strings containing some hex values.

```
String One = "f9 d4 62 aa f9 d4 62 aa 74 10 99 8b";
String Two = "3c 9c a7 e2 3c 9c a7 e2 b1 58 f9 d4";
```

Please note that the spaces in between the hex is generated by function that is converting binary to hex.Furthermore, the hex values are treated in pairs eg, f9 d4 is regarded as one pair.

My question is - how can I return the index (in this case, substring value) of two similar pair in the two strings?
The above example has f9 d4 in index 1 while the other String has it on index 6. So i want my output as (1,6) and (3,6).
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, why don't you want output of `(1,6) (3,6)`? What are you looking for when there are multiple matches? What about when there aren't any matches?

Comment: It would be easier to do this with the bytes before conversion, rather than processing the strings.

Comment: @chiastic-security, yes the actual string contains multiple pairs and i would need my output to display as you have mentioned. (1,6) and (3,6).

Comment: 1,6 and 3,6 don't make any sense to me here what is the significance of 1,3 3,6

Comment: (1,6)  First Pair (f9d4) in the first String is the same as the Sixth Pair (f9d4) in the second String....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider such code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String One = "f9 d4 62 aa f9 d4 62 aa 74 10 99 8b";
    String Two = "3c 9c a7 e2 3c 9c a7 e2 b1 58 f9 d4";

    int[] x = convert(One);
    int[] y = convert(Two);

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        int number = x[i];
        int index = find(number, y);
        if (index > 0) {
            System.out.println("found (" + (i + 1) + "," + index + ")");
        }
    }

}

private static int find(int number, int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == number) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

private static int[] convert(String str) {

    String[] tokens = str.split("\\s");
    int[] result = new int[tokens.length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i += 2) {
        String hex = tokens[i] + tokens[i + 1];
        result[i / 2] = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
found (1,6)
found (3,6)
```

As you can see `convert(str)` method converts each 4 hex digits into 1 integer and returns array of such integers. So convert(One) is simply int[] equal to:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
[63956, 25258, 63956, 25258, 29712, 39307]
```

Next you can implement helper method find() that returns index where number is found in given array (1-based index).

Comment: This is good supporting evidence that it's easier to do it with the raw values than with the hex string! If it's possible to get at the byte values before conversion, it would be easier to modify this approach to use them directly, rather than having to convert the string back to an `int[]`. But if you only have the strings to work with, this approach of converting to an `int[]` is a good one.

Comment: @przemek hertel , Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate your time, effort and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

hope it help !

```
String one = "f9 d4 62 aa f9 d4 62 aa 74 10 99 8b";
String two = "3c 9c a7 e2 3c 9c a7 e2 b1 58 f9 d4";

String[] oneArr = one.split(" ");
String[] twoArr = two.split(" ");

ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();      

for(int i = 0, countOne = 0 ; i < oneArr.length - 1 ; i = i + 2,countOne++) {

    String hexCoupleOne = oneArr[i] + " " + oneArr[i + 1];

    if(two.contains(hexCoupleOne)) {
        //searching index in two . . .
        for(int j = 0, countTwo = 0  ; j < twoArr.length - 1 ; j = j + 2, countTwo++) {
            String hexCoupleTwo = twoArr[j] + " " + twoArr[j + 1];
            if(hexCoupleOne.equals(hexCoupleTwo))
                results.add((countOne + 1) + "," + (countTwo + 1));
        }           
    }       
}

System.out.println("total pair : "+results.size());
for(String res : results) {
    System.out.println("Found a pair at index="+res.split(",")[0]+" in String one and at index="+res.split(",")[1]+" in String two." );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More efficient approach is not to search second string each time, but instead transform it into more suitable data structure, such as hash map where key is string pair and value is the list of positions when this pair appears. This complexity of such approach is `O(n)`, comparing to O(n<sup>2</sup>) when you search second string each time. This difference will be significant when you have bigger input strings.

```
    /**
     * Splits argument into substrings of lengths 6 and puts them into Map
     * where key is substring and value is the list of positions where substring appears 
     * in original string.
     * @param str string to split
     * @return Map of positions
     */
    private static Map<String, List<Integer>> indexMapOfPairs(String str) {
        Map<String, List<Integer>> result = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 6) {
            String pair = str.substring(i, i + 5);
            List<Integer> indexList = result.get(pair);
            if (indexList == null) {
                indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>(4);
                result.put(pair, indexList);
            }
            indexList.add(i / 6 + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String one = "f9 d4 62 aa f9 d4 62 aa 74 10 99 8b";
        String two = "3c 9c a7 e2 3c 9c a7 e2 b1 58 f9 d4";

        Map<String, List<Integer>> oneAsMap = indexMapOfPairs(one);
        Map<String, List<Integer>> twoAsMap = indexMapOfPairs(two);

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> oneEntry : oneAsMap.entrySet()) {
            String pair = oneEntry.getKey();
            List<Integer> twoIndices = twoAsMap.get(pair);
            if (twoIndices != null) {
                for (Integer oneIndex : oneEntry.getValue()) {
                    for (Integer twoIndex : twoIndices) {
                        System.out.printf("(%d, %d)%n", oneIndex, twoIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```